# After upgrade Flyway from 5.1 to 5.2 getting Migration type mismatch error with type SPRING_JDBC

Tags: java, flyway

After upgrading Flyway from 5.1.4 to 5.2.4 I get a FlywayException due to migration type validation while calling *Flyway.migrate*:

```
Migration type mismatch for migration eu.example.test.db.migration.repeatable.R__Fill_Event_Type_Table
-> Applied to database : SPRING_JDBC
-> Resolved locally    : JDBC | (Main.java:273) 
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Migration type mismatch for migration eu.example.test.db.migration.repeatable.R__Fill_Event_Type_Table
-> Applied to database : SPRING_JDBC
-> Resolved locally    : JDBC
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1482)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:85)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1364)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1356)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1711)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356)
```

I've fixed all deprecated warnings in the Java based migrations and migrated my old `SpringJdbcMigration` migrations classes to extend my own `JdbcBaseJavaMigration`:

```
public abstract class JdbcBaseJavaMigration extends BaseJavaMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
        migrate(new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(context.getConnection(), true)));
    }

    /**
     * Migrate with a {@link JdbcTemplate} (redirect from {@link #migrate(Context)}).
     * @param jdbcTemplate The {@link JdbcTemplate}.
     * @throws Exception when the migration failed.
     */
    public abstract void migrate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) throws Exception;

    @Override
    public boolean isUndo() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After starting my application all old migrations of type **SPRING_JDBC** are changed to type **JDBC** (I think it happens in the *Flyway.repair* call) accept
the repeatable migrations. All repeatable from package `eu.example.test.db.migration.repeatable` still have the type **SPRING_JDBC** in the *flyway_schema_history* table
and are causing the validation error.

What am I doing wrong?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53727504/7489056) this won't be fixed in 5.2.x.

Comment: I've experienced the same using flyway 5.2.4. Upgrading to 6.5.5 solved the issue.